# Using TeXworks to compile "several times" automatically

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, texworks

I am trying to create a simple bibliography in LaTeX and found this simple example on a tutorial site.

*bibliography.tex*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\title{Biblography}
\author{Dan}
\date{October 2016}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Specs}
\section{Introduction}
Using \texttt{biblatex} you can display bibliography divided into sections, 
depending of citation type. 
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 
Next, \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Donald 
Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}, \textit{The Comprehensive Tex Archive 
Network} (CTAN) \cite{ctan} are \LaTeX\ related items; but the others Donald 
Knuth's items \cite{knuth-fa,knuth-acp} are dedicated to programming.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

*sample.bib*

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    title={LaTeX Companion Book},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@online{ctan,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "CTAN",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@inbook{knuth-acp,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

I was informed that if you selected `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` on `TeXworks` you did not have to go through the process of running the compilation of the documents in this order.

```
pdfLaTeX
BibTex
pdfLaTeX
pdfLaTeX
```

However, when I use the option `pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` it causes the same citation warnings that are eliminated using the compilation process described above instead of eliminating them. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or help me fix the problem.

Comment: Note that your code is *not* using `biblatex`, but standard BibTeX. I have removed the tag and added the bibliography tag instead.

Comment: @moewe Sorry for any confusion caused